# create db.connection custom class wrapper, keep getting "django.db.utils.InterfaceError: cursor already closed"

Tags: python, django, class, django-database

im trying to make custom class wrapper for "django.db.connection",
but im keep getting "django.db.utils.InterfaceError: cursor already closed".

the working code is something like this if without custom class wrapper (copied from `./manage.py shell`) :

```py
>>> from django.db import (connection as con)
>>> with con.cursor() as q:
...     q.execute('select * from master.years a where a.years = %s', [str(2019)])
...     f = [f.name for f in q.description]
...     for b in q:
...             print(dict(zip(f,b)))
```

my wrapper `webapp/mine/db.py` :

```py
class query_00:
    def __init__(self, db_con, db_sql, db_stmt = []):
        self.db_con = db_con
        self.db_sql = db_sql
        self.fields = []

        with db_con.cursor() as self.query:
            self.query.execute(db_sql, db_stmt)
            self.fields = [f.name for f in self.query.description]

        # for entry in self.query:
            # yield dict(zip(self.fields, entry))

        # self.query = db_con.cursor()

    # must return self, because
    # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'result'
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
        # self.query.execute(self.db_sql, self.db_stmt)
        # self.fields = [f.name for f in self.query.description]
        # pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        # is this necessary?
        # self.db_con.close()
        pass

    def result(self):
        for entry in self.query.fetchall():
            yield dict(zip(self.fields, entry))

        # not working
        # for entry in self.query:
            # yield dict(zip(self.fields, entry))

        # not working
        # yield dict(zip(self.fields, entry))

        # pass
```

then i try it on `./manage.py shell`by typing

```py
from django.db import (connection as con)
from mine.db import query_00
```

```py
# expected usage, attempt 1
q = query_00(con, 'SELECT * FROM master.years a where a.year = %s', [str(2019),])
for b in q.result():
    print(b)
```

```py
# expected usage, attempt 2
with query_00(con, 'SELECT * FROM master.years a where a.year = %s', [str(2019),]) as q:
    for b in q.result():
        print(b)
```

python-3,django-2,postgresql-9

*(sorry for my english)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after reading the documentation, i realize that the connection was closed inside my init method.

```py
class query_00:
    def __init__(self, db_con, db_sql, db_stmt = []):
        self.db_con = db_con
        self.db_sql = db_sql
        self.fields = []

        with db_con.cursor() as self.query:
            self.query.execute(db_sql, db_stmt)
            self.fields = [f.name for f in self.query.description]
        # the connection only happend inside "with:" block
        # the connection, was already closed here (after with:)
```

so, i just have to keep cursor() on a variable

```py
class query_01:
    def __init__(self, db_sql, db_stmt):
        self.db_sql = db_sql
        self.db_stmt = db_stmt
        self.query = connection.cursor()
...
```

put `query.execute()` on another method

```py
...
    def execute(self):
        self.query.execute(self.db_sql, self.db_stmt)
        self.fields = [f.name for f in self.query.description]
...
```

on result()

```py
...
    def result(self):
        self.execute()
        for entry in self.query:
            yield self.keyvalue(entry)
...
```

then my class is working

```py
with query_00('SELECT * FROM master.years a where a.year = %s', [str(2019),]) as q:
    for b in q.result():
        print(b)
```